# Hover effect with drop down menu doesn't cover desired elements

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, dropdown

I'm trying to make a simple drop down side menu by making use of sibling elements and applying the hide/show effect on hover by the adjacent selector (+). It works almost flawlessly except for one annoying detail: the hover is supposed to be applied to both siblings, but there seems to be an empty void between them so that when the cursor leaves the first element it hides the other sibling back because it's not hovering any of them anymore.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/78dyfjw4/)

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
  <a>Item 1</a>
  <h1>Title 2</h1>
  <p>Item 2</p>
  <h1>Title 3</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 3.1</li>
    <li>Item 3.2</li>
    <li>Item 3.3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown {
    text-align: left;
    color: #00F;
    background-color: transparent;
}
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    width: 290px !important;
    color: #F00;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-top: 13px;
    line-height: 30px !important;
}
h1 a,
h1 a:visited {
    color: #FFFDFD;
}
h1:nth-of-type(1) + * {
    display: block;
}
h1 + * {
    display: none;
}
h1:hover + *,
h1 + *:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

I know I could just wrap them into a parent-child relationship, but within the scope I'm working on this is not possible. Another workaround could be that instead of setting display:none to hide and then display:block to show them on hover, I could set a max-height to 0 and then set something like max-height to whatever size and in order to escape the void between the siblings, I just needed to set a transition effect of .5s or even 1s long so that the user has enough time to put his cursor on the second sibling before it hides back, but the main problem with it is that chances are that there might be a table as one of the hidden elements and as we know it's not possible to set height to a table so it would never be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/78dyfjw4/1/

Hello there!
I just changed the

```
h1:nth-of-type(1) + * {
    display: block;
}
```

To

```
h1:nth-of-type(0) + * {
    display: block;
}
```

here's the full code

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1.1</li>
    <li>Item 2.2</li>
    <li>Item 3.3</li>
  </ul>
  <h1>Title 2</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 2.1</li>
    <li>Item 2.2</li>
    <li>Item 2.3</li>
  </ul>
  <h1>Title 3</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 3.1</li>
    <li>Item 3.2</li>
    <li>Item 3.3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown {
    text-align: left;
    color: #00F;
    background-color: transparent;
}
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    width: 290px !important;
    color: #F00;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-top: 13px;
    line-height: 30px !important;
}
h1 a,
h1 a:visited {
    color: #FFFDFD;
}
h1:nth-of-type(0) + * {
    display: block;
}
h1 + * {
    display: none;
}
h1:hover + *,
h1 + *:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood my problem (or rather I didn't explain it very well). The first <h1> is supposed to show its content, that's the way I want it. The problem is the other two <h1> elements. The part with `h1:hover + *, h1 + *:hover` is what's not working because, as you can see, the hover should happen on each of the h1's siblings  (in this case, the <ul> elements), but you can never get to hover them because there seems to be an empty void between the "Title 2" and "Item 2.1" "Item 2.2" "Item 2.3", or "Title 3" and  "Item 3.1" "Item 3.2" "Item 3.3" etc.